# SQL Convert DateTime Error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

```
SELECT dish_category.Cat_Name, order_items.OI_Name, dish_management.D_Price, order_items.OI_Quantity, order_items.OI_Price, order_management.O_Time
FROM dish_category 
INNER JOIN dish_management ON dish_category.Cat_ID = dish_management.Cat_ID 
INNER JOIN order_items ON dish_management.D_ID = order_items.D_ID 
INNER JOIN order_management ON order_items.O_ID = order_management.O_ID
WHERE order_management.O_Time = (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, date, 103),103)) BETWEEN @DSStart_date AND @DSEnd_date)
```

Can you please guide me where the query might be wrong? The error message is:

> Error in list of function arguments ',' not recognized unable to parse
>   query text

Answer (score 0):

- You've made too many calls to `CONVERT`. You only need 2: One for converting the date column into `varchar`, and one for converting the result to a `datetime` format.
- When calling `CONVERT(varchar, date)` You only pass 2 argument, the `103` is for date conversion, not `varchar` conversion.
- If you want to use today's date, use `DATE(NOW())` like I did below:

Try this:

```
SELECT dish_category.Cat_Name, order_items.OI_Name, dish_management.D_Price, 
order_items.OI_Quantity, order_items.OI_Price, order_management.O_Time

FROM dish_category INNER JOIN dish_management ON dish_category.Cat_ID = dish_management.Cat_ID 
INNER JOIN order_items ON dish_management.D_ID = order_items.D_ID 
INNER JOIN order_management ON order_items.O_ID = order_management.O_ID

WHERE (DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN @DSStart_date AND @DSEnd_date)
```

Comment: Now it shows Error in list of function arguments ')' not recognized unable to parse query text "

Comment: Did you use my latest update? Please note I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, WHERE (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar, date),103) BETWEEN @DSStart_date AND @DSEnd_date)

Comment: When you write `CONVERT(varchar, date)` What is `date`?  Is it a column? Where is it from ?

Comment: i am using TableAdapter where i am calling it from database as a "Select which returns row"

Comment: Now it shows Error in list of function arguments '(' not recognized unable to parse query text "

Comment: actually i am using report viewer there i am calling report from start date to end date.

Comment: WHERE order_management.O_Time (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATE),103) BETWEEN @DSStart_date AND @DSEnd_date)

Comment: " order_management.O_Time " this parameter is uses in database as O_Time so i can search from there that if order is delivered on that day or not

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently using SQL Server syntax for `CONVERT()` rather than MySQL syntax.

I don't know what `date` is, but this version of the query comes to mind:

```
SELECT c.Cat_Name, order_items.OI_Name, m.D_Price, oi.OI_Quantity,
       oi.OI_Price, om.O_Time
FROM dish_category c INNER JOIN
     dish_management m
     ON c.Cat_ID = m.Cat_ID INNER JOIN
     order_items oi
     ON m.D_ID = oi.D_ID INNER JOIN
     order_management om
     ON oi.O_ID = om.O_ID
WHERE om.O_Time BETWEEN @DSStart_date AND @DSEnd_date
```

Or, better yet:

```
WHERE om.O_Time >= @DStart_date AND @DSEnd_Date;
```

Of course, your code also contains:

```
(CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, date, 103),103))
```

I have no idea what this is supposed to be doing, stuck in the `where` clause between a column name and `BETWEEN`.